I started getting errors Feature is currently unavailable due to an internal error 1073740791
I'm working on a Blazor app, using VS 2022 Enterprise Edition. Version 17.12.0. Suddenly I started getting several errors that all appear below VS's toolbar:

I've searched for this error and found this on Microsoft's Learn website. The discouraging thing is people don't see to have a real solution. Some people claim that if they repair VS 2022 it seems to work for a while, but then after a week it goes back to causing problems. And VS doesn't give you any indication where in the code this is happening. At the moment I'm getting 18 of those type of errors.
Has anyone anything more promising?

That linked article has nothing to do with this problem.  The error is nasty, buffer overflows are big hairy problems.  Other users don't have this problem.  The version number suggests you recently updated VS, it might not have gone well with a file not getting updated.  A clean install is advisable.

@HansPassant you are correct, I have recently upgraded VS 2022. I could do an uninstall and reinstall of VS 2022. However, some of the comments in the thread I referenced indicated that other people tried doing that, with older versions of VS, and it didn't resolve the issue. I don't have a lot of confidence that will resolve the issue, but it is worth a try.

That linked article has nothing to do with this problem
